# validity of x-google-token

Tags: xmpp, authentication, access-token

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6194899/199675) post. As per the post everything works fine for me, but still I have a suspect for the validity of the auth token. Is there any validity for that token? I tried to login with the same token after 2 days, it worked for me.