# Is there an API to access Chrome Sync data?

Tags: api, google-chrome, bookmarks

If I wanted to make an application (not a Chrome extension) that accesses, let's say, your Chrome-synced bookmarks, would I have to reverse-engineer the interface that Chrome/Chromium uses? Or is there a published API for that?

Comment: Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524760/how-to-authenticate-with-chrome-sync-xmpp-servers

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Syncable Service API:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/design-documents/sync/syncable-service-api

EDIT 2020-03-27 The site mentions the information is outdated and suggests to go here instead:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/sync/model_api.md