# How to access Chrome's online bookmarks?

Tags: api, google-chrome, synchronization, reverse-engineering, bookmarks

Google Chrome allows you to sign in with your Google account to sync bookmarks and settings. Those bookmarks are then stored along with my account on their servers.

I want to create another client for the bookmarks. Please note that I am not interested in reading the local bookmarks file from hard disk. Instead I want to connect with the online servers directly.

So I need to access the same API as Chrome uses for synching. Is there a way to find out how to use that API?

Comment: I am not sure if helps or not but refer [this](https://code.google.com/p/gmarks-android/wiki/BookmarksAPI) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524760/how-to-authenticate-with-chrome-sync-xmpp-servers). Hope you get the solution soon.

Comment: Hi! Did you find solution for this?

Comment: @Zéiksz No, I think it is not possible. You could only look into source of Chromium and mimic the same behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whilst not using an API directly it allows you to query data from google bookmarks online (directly via REST call), and parse it yourself.

```
http://www.google.com/bookmarks/?output=xml&num=10000
```

I have included a link on how you may parse this data from the "Lite Bookmarks" chrome extension repository.
[http://www.google.com/bookmarks/?output=xml&num=10000](https://github.com/miscalencu/Google-Chrome-Google-Bookmarks/blob/master/js/core.js#L70)

Comment: There is a different between Google bookmarks and chrome bookmark. The url provided is for the Google bookmark, not the Chrome.

Comment: Besides Google Bookmarks is not the same thing as Google Chrome's bookmarks feature, Google Bookmarks itself is being [discontinued by Google](https://alternativeto.net/news/2021/7/google-bookmarks-is-being-discontinued-september-30th-2021/).