# How to programatically access the saved passwords in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-sync

API for Google Chrome Sync ?

I have already been through [How to authenticate with Chrome sync XMPP servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524760/how-to-authenticate-with-chrome-sync-xmpp-servers) , but the answer is 2 years old, and might not be applicable now.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to do? Are you writing a chrome extension?

Comment: I am writing an application to fetch saved passwords/bookmarks/history from the Google Account. If it can be done without involving Chrome, I would be happy. But if it necessarily requires to write a Chrome extension and fetch it from there, I can manage that as well.

Comment: @BageshwarPratapNarain I am trying to import all chrome passwords into a chrome extension/plugin.  Is that a possibility?

Comment: I am still waiting for someone to answer that question for me!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Chrome or the Chrome backend expose any public APIs to do this. You could try reverse engineering the APIs by looking at chrome's source code (it is open source), but that might be a significant undertaking.

Comment: Is the Chrome Sync part of Chromium open-source code, though? After all, Chrome != Chromium

Comment: Yes, chrome sync is built into chromium.