# XMPP Google-like solution for sync server notifications

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, xmpp, server-side

I'm looking for an easy way to implement the XMPP server running with the following protocol:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/rawxmpp

The only difference is that I must use X-GOOGLE-TOKEN authentication mechanism: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6211324/227244

The procedure is simple: I get the token from the data sent by a client, request user data based on this token and set the JID accordingly, appending some random chars to the resulting JID.

After that other clients with possibly different tokens, but same user account, connect to the XMPP resource and for clients who are subscribed the broadcast of push notifications is enabled.

What amount of the server code can be borrowed from the currently available implementations? I would avoid writing all of the server code myself, though the logic is pretty simple. I know there're ejabberd and prosody xmpp servers which implement lots of XEP. Which one is easier to add the custom handling mechanism to? Can you suggest other stable alternatives for the core xmpp server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way google has designed `X-OAUTH2` is dead simple and straightforward to implement. Infact, there is no difference between how `PLAIN` and `X-OAUTH2` mechanisms work. You can simply pick a standard `PLAIN` implementation and make it work for google `X-OAUTH2` authentication mechanism with no extra effort.

I am author of [Jaxl PHP library](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/) and I [recently announced](http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2012/09/how-to-perform-x-facebook-platform-and-google-talk-x-oauth2-xmpp-authentication-with-php-jaxl-library/) support for `X-OAUTH2` inside the library. [Here](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/commit/f42e0505b0f3374beea06de559b6574e793e8aff) you can see exact lines of code I had to write to support this. The only relevant piece of code is:

```
switch($mechanism) {
    case 'PLAIN':
    case 'X-OAUTH2':
        $stanza->t(base64_encode("\x00".$user."\x00".$pass));
        break;
```

For `X-OAUTH2` implementation `$pass` is nothing but your oauth token. In short, password field from `PLAIN` auth mechanism becomes oauth token for `X-OAUTH2` mechanism. Rest all remains the same.